# Bootstrap navigation and sidebar on one row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, sidebar

I am developing a page with Bootstrap and what I am trying to achieve is something like this picture: 
[image]

My initial thought was to have a nav and aside elements which will be 3 and 9 columns. However, the nav and the aside don't float next to each other, instead start from the top left corner and stack on top of each other.

I am just starting with Bootstrap and any help will be much appreciated!

**index.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-sm-9 navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!--  nav content here -->
        </nav>

        <aside class="col-sm-3">
         <!--  aside content here -->
        </aside>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of Bootstrap like Lego... each block serves a purpose.  You're dealing with two distinctly different "blocks" (and their behaviour).  The grid, and the nav bar.

Where things fall apart in the code you supplied is that it's trying to make a grid column behave like a navbar: `... class="col-sm-9 navbar ...`

It is better to structure the the page as independent blocks.  First the grid, and then the navbar inside the grid.  Example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        ...
      </nav>

      Rest of the content goes here...

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">

      <asside>
        Logo
        Link, etc.
      </aside>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinorodrigues/ejryjLt8/1/) for a working example.

Comment: The problem with my approach was that I was using navbar-fixed-top. After I removed it, I could arrange it how I wanted. But the navigation was going on top of the aside as if the picture did not wanted to fit into the grid. However, your structure makes a lot more sense.